# I am trying to install T32 software using Linux command. However, I am stuck at "No screen library found"

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, lauterbach

[[No screen library found[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFVOg.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjsHp.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5yRP.jpg)

I have tried using command ldd to view the library, however it say no such file or directory.

Answer (score 1):

The version of TRACE32 you are using requires either an installed **Qt 5** library or an installed **Motif** library.

If Qt 5 is installed TRACE32 uses its screen library "t32screeqt5.so". If Qt 5 is missing but Motif is present, TRACE32 uses its screen library "t32screencde.so".

Looks like your Linux is missing both Qt 5 and Motif.